# RecyclerView calls onBindViewHolder() on all items [No ScrollView Involved]

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use a RecyclerView in an Android app (API 23+) and update its adapter with around 380 items. Even though only 15 items are visible, the RecyclerView's adapter's onBindViewHolder() method gets called for all 380 items. Some threads describe that this happens when the RecyclerView is inside a ScrollView or NestedScrollView; however, that is not the case here. Another suggestion is to set the width of the recycler view to 0dp or to set its height to wrap-content. Neither tip works in this case.

Here is a graphic of the navigation graph:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TABLE TITLE-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/mid_gray"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_table_title_0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="@string/caja"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_table_title_variedad"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/variedad"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_table_title_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ingreso"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_table_title_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:text="@string/semanas"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_table_title_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cantidad"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the adapter code

```
package com.plantecuador.poscosecha.adapter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.plantecuador.poscosecha.R;
import com.plantecuador.poscosecha.db.entities.BoxInside;
import com.plantecuador.poscosecha.event.BoxInsideSelectedEvent;
import com.plantecuador.poscosecha.helper.DateFormatHelper;
import com.plantecuador.poscosecha.viewholder.ThrowOutViewHolder;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils;
import org.threeten.bp.Instant;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;
import org.threeten.bp.temporal.ChronoUnit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import timber.log.Timber;

public class ThrowOutAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ThrowOutViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<BoxInside> insides = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ThrowOutViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_throw_out, parent, false);
        return new ThrowOutViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ThrowOutViewHolder vh, int position) {
        Timber.v("onBindViewHolder called in throwout and position %s", position);
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            vh.rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            vh.rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));
        }

        BoxInside inside = insides.get(position);
        vh.txtInsideNumber.setText(inside.getId());

        Date date = (inside.getDateCFOrigPacked() == null) ? inside.getDatePacked() : inside.getDateCFOrigPacked();

        String strDate = DateFormatHelper.formatToDateString("dd/MM/yy", date);
        vh.txtDate.setText(strDate);
        vh.txtQuantity.setText(inside.getQuantity() + "");
        vh.txtVariety.setText(inside.getVariety() + "");

        Instant instantStart = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date);
        LocalDateTime localStart = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instantStart, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        Instant instantEnd = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(new Date());
        LocalDateTime localEnd = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instantEnd, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        long weeks = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(localStart, localEnd);
        vh.txtAge.setText(weeks + "");

        assert vh.btnVer != null;
        vh.btnVer.setOnClickListener(view -> EventBus.getDefault().post(new BoxInsideSelectedEvent(inside)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return insides.size();
    }

    public void update(List<BoxInside> insides) {
        this.insides.clear();
        this.insides.addAll(insides);
        Timber.v("About to notify dataset changed");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The behavior is as follows: The adapter's update() method is called with a new list of BoxInside objects when there are updates. I'd like the RecyclerView to obviously clear, update it's dataset, and update the view but not worry about creating ViewHolders outside the visible area until the user scrolls.

Comment: lets see your adapter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from a RelativeLayout to a FrameLayout fixes it. Here is the navigation hierarchy after the fix.

[image]